# How to pull data from one excel cell into html page?

Tags: jquery, html

I have one excel file which will be filled by many users. 
How can I pull data from cell B2 for example, to be placed somewhere in HTML page using jQuery?

Comment: you're going to need to provide more details on what you want to accomplish? Are you using c# to try to automatically pull that cell value in?

Comment: HTML alone won't be able to accomplish this.  What programming language are you using?

Comment: I know I can't do it using HTML alone. I edited my question now :D

Answer (score 0):

copy the cell contents with `CTRL + C`

paste the cell contents into a .html file with `CTRL + V`

:D

Comment: technically, a legitimate answer.

Comment: I get it, my question wasn't right :D I changed the question